# How to correctly deploy Next Js applications in kubernetes cluster with environments variables

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, next.js, environment-variables

I need my Next js application to read the .env file when deployed to kubernetes.
What I do for this:

1. As we know, in order for the next js application to read the .env file, this file must already be in the root folder of the application, before the "npm run build" command. So I create a docker file with this instruction "CMD npm run build; npm run start" so that when kubernetes deploy the container, it first does "npm run build" and after "npm run start".

---

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN groupadd -g 1001 -r nodejs
RUN useradd -u 1001 -r nextjs
RUN mkdir -p /app/.next/cache/images && chown nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/cache/images
RUN chown -R nextjs /app/.next
VOLUME /app/.next/cache/images
USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run build; npm run start
```

---

2. When deploying the application with "kubectl apply -f ...", I drop the env file into the root folder of the application using config map.

---

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: environment-variables
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
data:
  .env: |-
    CMS_URL=http://192.168.****:13**/
    FRONT_URL=http://192.168.****:32***/
    AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.****:32***
    RESOURCE_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.****:31***
    PORT=3000
    NODE_ENV=production
    NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
    NEXT_PUBLIC_CMS_URL=http://192.168.****:1***/
    NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_URL=http://192.168.****:32***/
    NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.****:32***
    NEXT_PUBLIC_RESOURCE_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.****:31***
    NEXT_PUBLIC_PORT=3000
    NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV=production
    NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: register-next-deployment
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.name }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: platformdevvops-registry-key
      containers:
      - name: registernext
        image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: {{ .Values.container.port }}
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /app/.env
            name: environment-variables
            readOnly: true
            subPath: .env
      volumes:
        - name: environment-variables
          configMap:
            name: environment-variables
            items:
              - key: .env
                path: .env
```

In this way, my application successfully reads the env file. But I don't like this method. Are there other ways to do this? I need my .env file to get into the container during deployment to Kubernetes cluster and be read by the application.

Comment: The PNG files you've linked to can't be used to reproduce the problem.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] directly in the question; not as links, and as plain text and not images?

Comment: didn't get meaning of `at the same time I need the .env file to be read during the deployment of kuberntes`

Comment: Does next.js actually require this .env file or can it read system environment variables directly? If so, you can just specify them as environment variables in the k8s container without needing to inject a file.

Comment: Use `init container` to dump your values from the configMap to .env file. Init containers run before the main container and they share same resources in the pod. Here are the ddocs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/